# How to push object into an array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function

I am trying to do use the angular push function but it is not working.

I want to add strings (or objects) into an array.

I searched for basic examples here at Stack Overflow but I couldn't find it.

Can anyone correct my code or write a very basic example?

Here is my example.

**This is the HTML code:**

```
<form ng-controller="TestController as testCtrl ng-submit="testCtrl.addText(myText)">
    <input type="text" value="Lets go">
    <button type="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

**This is the Java Script code:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('TestController', function() {
        this.arrayText = {
            text1: 'Hello',
            text2: 'world',
        }

        this.addText = function(text) {
            arrayText.push(this.text);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but `this.arrayText` is an object, it has no `push`, and it's not the same as just `arrayText` ?

Comment: `<form ng-controller="TestController as testCtrl ng-submit="testCtrl.addText(myText)">` Is this correct? missing a `"`? (also, arrayText has an extra comma).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Push only work for array .

Make your `arrayText` object to Array Object.

Try Like this

**JS**

```
this.arrayText = [{
  text1: 'Hello',
  text2: 'world',
}];

this.addText = function(text) {
  this.arrayText.push(text);
}
this.form = {
  text1: '',
  text2: ''
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as testCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="addText(form)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.text1" value="Lets go">
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.text2" value="Lets go again">
    <input type="submit" value="add">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Button type should be submit.

Answer (score 15):

Please check this - http://plnkr.co/edit/5Sx4k8tbWaO1qsdMEWYI?p=preview

Controller-

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    this.arrayText = [{text:'Hello',},{text: 'world'}];

    this.addText = function(text) {

      if(text) {
        var obj = {
          text: text
        };
          this.arrayText.push(obj);
          this.myText = '';
          console.log(this.arrayText);
        }
      } 
 });
```

HTML

```
<form ng-controller="TestController as testCtrl" ng-submit="testCtrl.addText(testCtrl.myText)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="testCtrl.myText" value="Lets go">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in testCtrl.arrayText">
            <span>{{item}}</span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

'Push' is for arrays.

You can do something like this:

app.js:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.myText = "Let's go";

    $scope.arrayText = [
            'Hello',
            'world'
        ];

    $scope.addText = function() {
        $scope.arrayText.push(this.myText);
    }

 }]);

})();
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form ng-controller="myController" ng-submit="addText()">
           <input type="text" ng-model="myText" value="Lets go">
           <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
           <pre>list={{arrayText}}</pre>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            //Comments object having reply oject
            $scope.comments = [{ comment: 'hi', reply: [{ comment: 'hi inside commnet' }, { comment: 'hi inside commnet' }] }];

            //push reply
            $scope.insertReply = function (index, reply) {
                $scope.comments[index].reply.push({ comment: reply });
            }

            //push commnet
            $scope.newComment = function (comment) {
                $scope.comments.push({ comment:comment, reply: [] });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <!--Comment section-->
        <ul ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index" style="background: skyblue; padding: 10px;">
            <li>
                <b>Comment {{$index}} : </b>
                <br>
                {{comment.comment}}
                <!--Reply section-->
                    <ul ng-repeat="reply in comment.reply track by $index">
                        <li><i>Reply {{$index}} :</i><br>
                            {{reply.comment}}</li>
                    </ul>
                <!--End reply section-->
                <input type="text" ng-model="reply" placeholder=" Write your reply." /><a href="" ng-click="insertReply($index,reply)">Reply</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--End comment section -->
            

        <!--Post your comment-->
        <b>New comment</b>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your comment" ng-model="comment" />
        <a href="" ng-click="newComment(comment)">Post </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi, This answer really helped to me , but I need to add remove reply and comment button too . how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of answers that should work above but this is how i would write it.

Also, i wouldn't declare controllers inside templates. It's better to declare them on your routes imo.

add-text.tpl.html

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <form ng-submit="addText(myText)">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Let's Go" ng-model="myText">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="text in arrayText">{{ text }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

app.js

```
(function() {

    function myController($scope) {
        $scope.arrayText = ['hello', 'world'];
        $scope.addText = function(myText) {
             $scope.arrayText.push(myText);     
        };
    }

    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('myController', myController);

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this way. It will definitely work.

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.myText = "Object Push inside ";

    $scope.arrayText = [

        ];

    $scope.addText = function() {
        $scope.arrayText.push(this.myText);
    }

 }]);

})();
```

In your case `$scope.arrayText` is an object. You should initialize as a array.