# Push Item From One Array Into another Array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am programming an app with AngularJS and wanted to know how to push an item from one array into another array.

Here is sample code:

```
$scope.tasks = [
     {title: "Do the dishes"},
     {title: "Walk the dog"},
];
$scope.addToTasksDone = function() {// IM FAILNG HERE};
$scope.tasksDone = [];
```

How can I push the item with value "Do the dishes" to the tasksDone array?

Comment: take out element from array, get its index & `splice` it, after that push it to another array

Comment: How do i take it out from this array?

Comment: pass unique value to function, loop through the list & find element by unique id

Comment: Do you have an example for that?

Comment: You could avoid playing with arrays and add an attribute "finished: true" to you task object. This would be better design in my opinion.

Comment: i need to do it like that because it should be like a taskplan for the day

Comment: i have the answer posted by myself, but i will give Piyush the Best answer cause he led me to the goal!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push object into an array using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484653/how-to-push-object-into-an-array-using-angularjs)

Comment: But with an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.tasks = [
{title: "Do the dishes"},
{title: "Walk the dog"},
];
$scope.tasksDone = [];
$scope.addToTasksDone = function(index) {// IM FAILNG HERE};
$scope.tasksDone.push($scope.tasks[index]);
}
```

Comment: it only pushes the first item of the array.

Comment: It was just an example use index .

Comment: you have to provide index like $scope.addToTasksdone(1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.tasks.push(yourObject)
```

this question was aked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484653/how-to-push-object-into-an-array-using-angularjs/30484808)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.tasks = [
    { title: "Do the dishes" },
    { title: "Walk the dog" }
]; 
$scope.tasksDone = [];
for(var i in $scope.tasks){
    $scope.tasksDone.push($scope.tasks[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.tasks = [
{title: "Do the dishes"},
{title: "Walk the dog"},
];
 $scope.tasksDone = [];
angular.forEach(tasks , function(value, key) {
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
},tasksDone);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to push some specific value to the new array

```
$scope.tasks = [
     {title: "Do the dishes"},
     {title: "Walk the dog"},
];
$scope.tasksDone = [];
$scope.addToTasksDone = function(specificValue) {
                           // IM FAILNG HERE};
     tasks.forEach( (object) => {
          if ( object[title] === specificValue ) {
                $scope.tasksDone.push(object);
          }
     });
}
```

Above code will push each object which contain value as specific Value...
You can invoke addToTasksDone by passing "Do the dishes" value as parameter.

Sample invocation

```
$scope.addToTasksDone("Do the dishes");
```

Regards

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code.

I have the list inside a ng-repeat so i have to change `$scope.addToTasksDone(index)` to `$scope.addToTasksDone($index)`.

Ofcourse also in the `HTML` for **example**: 
`ng-click="addToTasksDone($index)`