# Push object from one array to another based on parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, filtering

So I have a list of news articles, and I need them to be filtered but server side not client side.

The way I'm filtering is by having a dropdown list that users click on to filter the articles like so:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
       <span href="" ng-click="getFilteredArticles(category.id)">{{category.title}}</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

and the articles are populated via an ng-repeat like so

```
<ul infinite-scroll="addPosts()" infinite-scroll-distance="0" infinite-scroll-disabled="stopScrolling" class="c-news">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts" class="c-news__item" ng-click="selectPost(post)">
        <!-- Omitted some code for the sake of brevity -->
     </li>
 </ul>
```

The getFilteredArticles method looks like this

```
 $scope.getFilteredArticles = function (categoryId) {

        var posts = $scope.posts;

        posts.forEach( (object) => {
            if ( object[Categories.Id] === categoryId ) {
                $scope.filteredArticles.push(object);
            }
        });

        console.log($scope.filteredArticles);
    }
```

A typical JSON object that I'm pulling through looks like this

```
{  
     "Title":"Test Title",
     "Summary":"",
     "PublishedDate":"2016-10-17T09:42:00",
     "Author":{  
        "Id":"480586a5-2169-e611-9426-00155d502902",
        "FirstName":"TestFirst",
        "LastName":"TestSecond",
        "Email":"test@test.com"
     },
     "Id":99,
     "StatusName":"Published",
     "Status":2,
     "Categories":[  
        {  
           "Id":1,
           "Name":"Category 1",
           "ArticleCount":31,
           "UnpublishedArticleCount":1
        },
        {  
           "Id":2,
           "Name":"Category 2",
           "ArticleCount":19,
           "UnpublishedArticleCount":0
        }
     ],
     "AttachmentCount":0,
     "FilesAwaitingCheckIn":0
  }
```

What I'd like to happen is when the user clicks one of the filter choices, for the list to then filter to the clicked choice. I've got this far but then I'm getting a ReferenceError: Categories is not defined.

I based my getFilteredArticles() code from another Stack question which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38160531/3816927).

I'm aware of being able to just filter the ng-repeat however my manager does not want to go that route and would rather filter server side due to the amount of posts that we may have.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Here's what's inside  [$scope.posts array](http://pastebin.com/5ELDDG1V)

Comment: If `Categories` is a property of `posts`, you should define it like this

`object["Categories"]["Id"] === categoryId`

Comment: Thanks for that Nishant, that has got me past that error. Now the console.log is just spitting out an empty array. Could it be due to each category id being inside a separate object within the Categories object?

Comment: I guess the `if` condition is not being met. You have used a strict check `===`. Check if both the types are same. There is a difference between `"2"` and `2`. Also debug the values inside the loop before `if` condition

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, so I console.log(object["Categories"]["id"]); this spits out an (20) undefined message. However when I remove ["id"] I get each objects categories object spat out. I'm guessing there's something wrong with traversing to id within the categories object?

Apologies if I'm missing something basic, I'm much more of a UI Designer than developer/programmer :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Can you update your question with `posts` array?

Comment: No problem, I've added it in.

Comment: I have created an example [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/6t3b9mzy/11/) based on the `json` you have posted. Please have a look. See the `console` output and let me know if this is what you are looking for. All the `Id`'s that match your provided `Id` are getting pushed into the `array`

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I think this is it. I'm going to have a play and report back!

Comment: Thanks. I have added an answer. Please accept it if you feel it solves your problem

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Categories` is an `array` you need to loop through that array to get `Id`'s

Your loop should be similar to this

```
$scope.getFilteredArticles = function (categoryId) {

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.posts.length;i++)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<$scope.posts[i]["Categories"].length;j++)
          {
            if($scope.posts[i]["Categories"][j]["Id"] == categoryId)
                $scope.filteredArticles.push($scope.posts[i])
          }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.filteredArticles));
    };
```