# Add new list options into the list box dynamically- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add new list options dynamically into the listbox. The getItem("newCompany") gets the array data from the local storage. This works well. But I'm unable to push the newCompany.name into the $scope.companies array. I am trying to add the new list options "Huawei and Asus" dynamically.

```html
var newCompany = [{
            name: "Huawei", // -->COMPANY NAME
            email: "Drath@yahoo.com",
            phone: "123-123-1234",
            owner: "Drath",
            street: "Gin Blvd",
            city: "Austin",
            country: "USA",
            duns:"123112321",
            type: "buyer"
        },
        {
            name: "Asus", // -->COMPANY NAME
            email: "Vadar@yahoo.com",
            phone: "999-123-8888",
            owner: "Vadar",
            street: "Vince Blvd",
            city: "Dallas",
            country: "USA",
            duns: "123100000",
            type: "supplier"
        }];

        window.localStorage.setItem("newCompany", JSON.stringify(newCompany));
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);   
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.companies = ["Apple", "Oneplus", "Samsung"];
    var newCompany = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCompany"));
    $scope.newComp = {};
    $scope.newComp.push(newCompany.name);
    $scope.companies.push($scope.newComp);
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="addCompany" placeholder="Select Company" ng-options="company for company in companies">
                                    </select>
```

Comment: I'm surprised your console didn't balk at this - Objects don't have a push method.

Comment: Push only work for array .

Make your newComp object to Array Object.

Comment: maybe this should helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484653/how-to-push-object-into-an-array-using-angularjs

Comment: @BartoszTermena Well I changed newComp={}; to [];. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do the data types match? 
`$scope.companies` contains strings, so try adding the string of the company name manually.

Also, `ng-options="company for company in companies"` - I'm not sure using the same variable name twice will work. ng-options is normally used to save company *objects* in `companies` so that the ng-model of the select will contain the selected company:

`<select ng-model="selectedCompany" ng-options="item.label for item in companies"></select>`